# Finding the top offset of a parent

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, offset

In JavaScript how can I get the correct offset position from the top of the red border? Basically, I want the "selected" class to line up the checkmark in the next column that is bolded by getting the offset of the red border.

Currently it's only getting the position of the td (which is the parent the selected element is in), but I want it to be the tbody.

See pen: https://codepen.io/billy-hunter/pen/ebvKEV

```css
#familyGroupModal .probTable tbody {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#familyGroupModal .probTable td.relationship-match {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#familyGroupModal .probTable .iconCheck:before {
  color: #6BA410;
}

#familyGroupModal .probTable .viewRelLink {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#familyGroupModal .probTable .selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#familyGroupModal .probTable .matchedArea {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Modal</title>
  <meta name="description" content=" " />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.ancestrycdn.com/ui/2.0.0-rc.4/css/core.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <button class="ancBtn" id="modal-btn1" type="button">Open Modal</button>
  <div id="familyGroupModal" class="modal modalHasTitle">
    <header class="modalHeader">
      <h4 class="modalTitle">test</h4>
    </header>


    <table class="table topSpacingBlock probTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" abbr="Name">Probability</th>
          <th scope="col" abbr="Relationship">Relationship</th>
          <th scope="col" abbr="Relationship Match"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="probability" class="text2xlrg bold">50%</td>
          <td data-label="relationship">
            <div>Jane Doe</div>
            <div>Jaeenen Doe</div>
            <div>Jimmy Doe</div>
            <div>Julie</div>
          </td>
          <td class="relationship-match">
            <div class="matchedArea">
              <span class="icon iconCheck"></span>
              <span class="hide480 bold">Match</span>
              <p class="noTopSpacing viewRelLink hide480"><a href="#">View</a></p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="probability" class="text2xlrg bold">40%</td>
          <td data-label="relationship">
            <div>Jane Doe</div>
            <div>Jenny Doe</div>
            <div class="selected">Joeneys Doe</div>
            <div>Jerry Donor</div>
          </td>
          <td class="relationship-match"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="probability" class="text2xlrg bold">7%</td>
          <td data-label="relationship">
            <div>Julie Doe</div>
            <div>Jamie Doo</div>
            <div>Jan Doe</div>
            <div>Janiee Dooo</div>
          </td>
          <td data-label="relationship-match"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="probability" class="text2xlrg bold">3%</td>
          <td data-label="relationship">
            <div>Jery Doe</div>
            <div>James Dooo</div>
            <div>Janeeie</div>
            <div>Jenny Down</div>
          </td>
          <td data-label="relationship-match"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script src="https://www.ancestrycdn.com/ui/2.0.0-rc.4/js/core.js"></script>

  <script>
    const familyGroupModal = ui.modal('#familyGroupModal', {

    });
    familyGroupModal.open();
    document.getElementById('modal-btn1').addEventListener('click', () => {
      familyGroupModal.open();
    });

    //add 'selected' class to relationship that matches, and offset the top of parent element.
    const selectedElem = document.querySelector('.selected');
    const parentElem = document.querySelector('.probTable tbody');
    const matchedArea = document.querySelector('.matchedArea');

    if (selectedElem) {
      matchedArea.style.top = selectedElem.offsetTop + "px";
      //console.log(selectedElem.offsetParent.offsetParent.offsetTop);
    } else {
      matchedArea.className = 'noDisplay';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.